# VB.Net momento temporal en que la ejecución ha pasado por un punto de interrupción

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

Tengo un programa en vb.net ejecutándose en debug. Durante este fin de semana se ha parado en un punto de interrupción que tengo definido. Hay alguna forma de saber en qué momento temporal (día y hora) ha pasado por ese punto de interrupción?

Gracias

Comment: Te refieres a que has estado debugueando un programa usando un IDE? Por ejemplo Visual Studio?

Comment: Si eso es, visual Studio 2019